# Can't install my own Google Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have created pretty easy extension that is working well in "load unpacked mode" and even as .crx file. But I can't install it from Chrome Store, it says "no file" while I trying to install it. Other users reporting about the same problem. Is there something at my side or google side?

ps. extension [page](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/imgleprosoriumcom/igbklfloandhoogdlppdegbaceppicop), [source code](https://github.com/crea7or/imgLeprosoriumCom).

Comment: And now it working good. Is there any kind of premoderation?

Answer (score 0):

[Google Chrome considers a file to be installable if either of the following is true](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/hosting.html):

```
The file has the content type application/x-chrome-extension
The file suffix is .crx and both of the following are true:
    The file is not served with the HTTP header X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
    The file is served with one of the following content types:
        empty string
        "text/plain"
        "application/octet-stream"
        "unknown/unknown"
        "application/unknown"
        "*/*"
```

Take a look [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/hosting.html)

Comment: So......? The Chrome Web Store should obviously serve the file with the correct MIME-type.

Comment: I'm not the OP, but he clearly says "But I can't install it from Chrome Store".

Comment: Extension started working after a few hours. At the same time when it appeared in search. However the status has been published all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, unfortunately mine stayed broken for 2 days. I managed to fix it simply by bumping up the version number and re-uploading the zip file.